# It should be two errors here but I can´t see them

Tags: java

New error:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMICalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Length in meters: ");
        double length = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Weight in kilos: ");
        double weight = input.nextDouble();

        double bmi = weight / length * length;

        System.out.printf("BMI");

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your IDE tell you?

Comment: What errors do you expect?

Comment: In your `System.out.printf`, you're using the non-existing `length` variable. As I understand, there should be `meter` variable there.

Comment: Well, one issue I see is that you close the input stream, while you haven't opened it. In your case, you are closing standard in. Here after, one is not able to read from it again.

Answer (score 1):

You're considering variables meter and bmi to be of type double. However, the expression on the right hand side of assignment is divide operation among int which will cause precision loss.

You'll need to cast one of the operands on right hand side to double to preserve precision.

```
double meter = (double) centimeter / 100;
double bmi = (double) weight / (meter * meter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `System.out.printf`, you're using the non-existing `length` variable. As I understand, there should be `meter` variable there.

I've also fixed a typo in first `System.out.print` in `Length` word.

The fixed class looks like this (*UPDATE:* also fixed the integer division, which was the actual question's target):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMICalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Length in centimeter: ");
        int centimeter = input.nextInt();
        double meter = ((double) centimeter) / 100; // fixed integer division by casting to double

        System.out.print("Weight in whole kilo: ");
        int weight = input.nextInt();

        double bmi = ((double) weight) / (meter * meter); // fixed integer division by casting to double

        System.out.printf("BMI for someone who is %.2f meter long, and weight %d kilo is %.1f", meter, weight, bmi);

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then please post the failing error. My class executes and works, I've tried it before posting.

Comment: At first, you have strings of different languages compared in your test cases (including the decimal separator formatting of `,` VS `.`. At second, have a look to @Dhruvil Vaghela answer. Most probably you're using an integer-division for your `meter` and `bmi` variables.

Comment: Thank you all for the help it worked now! It was the double meter that was missing:)

Comment: Ok, not at all. I guess the best SO action from your side is to accept Dhruvil's answer and upvote both of our answers.

Comment: I tried to execute your current class manually, it works. I guess you should post your unit-test code as well (or even better — upload the whole project to github).